# Objective C get html page's links

Tags: objective-c, web-services, networking, web

I'm quite new in Objective C programming and I'm trying to make an application that returns all the link addresses in HTML page. In that case i shouldn't just parse the HTML, but get these links intercepting them from the page's network request.

Is it possible to intercept the application's network requests or something?

Thanks

Comment: In what context do you want to intercept the page's network requests? (presenting webview, background, etc). Provide some more details and definitely some code.

Answer (score 1):

Coincidentally, Ray Wenderlich's rather AWESOME iOS tutorial site [posted this article](http://feedproxy.google.com/%7Er/RayWenderlich/%7E3/ACvPzelpOFc/how-to-parse-html-on-ios) in the last hour.   As you are new to iOS/ObjC, I highly recommend reading it thoroughly.

> Let’s say you want to find some information inside a web page and
> display it in a custom way in your app.
>
> This technique is called
> “scraping.” Let’s also assume you’ve thought through alternatives to
> scraping web pages from inside your app, and are pretty sure that’s
> what you want to do.
>
> Well then you get to the question – how can you
> programmatically dig through the HTML and find the part you’re looking
> for, in the most robust way possible? Believe it or not, regular
> expressions [won’t cut it!](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html)

And before you think Regular Expressions might really be an answer, [please read this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454).